# How to delete long name folders under subfolder using batch file

Tags: batch-file, filenames, subdirectory, delete-file

I am trying to delete the sub folders using batch file.
I have folder

1. c:\users\mis
2. c:\users\mis\A\Third Party Log
3. c:\users\mis\B\Third Party Log
4. c:\users\mis\C\Third Party
5. c:\users\mis\D\Third Party

Etc.
I want to delete all "Third Party Log" folder and I tire as below:

```
@echo off
Set MainFolder=C:\users\mis
FOR /D %%D IN ("%MainFolder%\*") DO CALL :RENAME %%D
pause & exit
REM -------------------------------------------------------
:RENAME
Set CRITERIA=Third Party Log
FOR /D %%R IN ("%1\%CRITERIA%") do @if exist "%%R" rd /s /q "%%R"
REM -------------------------------------------------------**
```

If the folder is only Third it is deleting.  Please help me deleting the fodlers.

Thanks,
Htet

Comment: I wouldn't perform the task like this myself, I'd probably consider something like this, `@For /D %%G In ("C:\Users\mis\*")Do @RD /S/Q "%%g\Third Party Log" 2>NUL`, or this, `@For /D /R "C:\Users\mis" %%G In ("Th?rd Party Log")Do @RD /S/Q "%%G"`, instead. However in your code, I would advise that you either change `:RENAME %%D` to `:RENAME "%%D"` and `%1` to `%~1`, or change `%1` to `%*`; _(I would advise you to choose the former)_.

Comment: Other than fixing my typo, in the first example, _(`%%g` should be `%%G`)_, the only good reason I can see for that behavior would be that the directories you are trying to remove aren't yours. Or more precisely, you do not have the necessary permissions to remove them. If you're using the first example, with the typo fix, you could also remove the `2>NUL` from the end to output any error messages.

Comment: hi @Compo It is working now.  Yes %%g make different.  Thanks alot.  You save my day.  Have a wonderful day and stay safe.

Comment: In your (overcomplicated) code you need to use quotation like `call :RENAME "%%~D"` and to replace `%1` with `%~1` and `"%%R"` with `"%%~R"`…

Answer (score 1):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
rem The following settings for the source directory, destination directory, target directory,
rem batch directory, filenames, output filename and temporary filename [if shown] are names
rem that I use for testing and deliberately include names which include spaces to make sure
rem that the process works using such names. These will need to be changed to suit your situation.

SET "targetdir=u:\your files"

SET "selectname=Third Party Log"

FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
 'dir /b /s /ad "%targetdir%\%selectname%" '
 ) DO (
 IF /i "%%~nxa"=="%selectname%" ECHO RD /S /Q "%%a"
)
```

Simply perform a `dir /b /ad` to list all of the directorynames matching the mask `%selectname%` and remove all of the hits.

Note that the `for` loop could be condensed to a single line, but I've split it over a number for clarity.

Naturally, the variables could be substituted by their literal values as well, if desired. This would reduce the entire batch to a single line which could be entered directly at the prompt in which case each `%%` needs to be reduced to a single `%`.

Posted code simply `echo`es the proposed instruction to allow for verification. I the displayed  instructions are correct, remove the `echo` keyword to actually destroy the unwanted directories.

Finally, in your original code, `rename` is not a good name for the subroutine for two reasons : First, it is misleading as no renaming is being performed and second, `ren` is an alias of `rename` - and it's not a good idea to have a routine or variable or label that is itself a command-name.

Comment: @user1202017 Please flag this as the anwser (the checkmark under the votes)

Answer (score 0):

I can sadly not write code and test it rn but:

You could use the dir command into a temp file.
Use findstr(or find i m not shure) and look for third party log.
Write this back to the temp file.
Now you should be left with a file filled with the paths of the folders you want gone.
Read the file line by line and delete and use this line string to provide the path for the del command.

To change the name as in the sample code you could take the line string and use it as the path to the ren command.

This is most likely a very bad approach but it should work.